# How to print non symmetric value while using for loop in Java

Tags: java, matrix, logic, jama

I want to implement a matrix using for loop. To create the matrix I  used Jama Matrix Package.

Here is my code

```
import Jama.Matrix;

public class Matrixnonsym {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
       Matrix Mytest=new Matrix(5,5);
       for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
           Mytest.set(i,i,1);
           Mytest.set(i+1,i,1);
       }
       Mytest.print(9,6);
   }
}
```

Here is my output:

```
1.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000
1.000000   1.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000
0.000000   1.000000   1.000000   0.000000   0.000000
0.000000   0.000000   1.000000   1.000000   0.000000
0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   1.000000   0.000000
```

There is no compilation error or runtime error. The difficulty is that how could I make the (0,0) cell value 2? As this matrix constructed using for loop so all value constructed symmetrically. Then how could I make only one cell with different value?

**Desire Output:**

```
2.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000
1.000000   1.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000
0.000000   1.000000   1.000000   0.000000   0.000000
0.000000   0.000000   1.000000   1.000000   0.000000
0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   1.000000   0.000000
```

Comment: If you need to set the matrix values using specific values, rather than calculations based on the the single index `i` then I don't think a for-loop is appropriate. Why do you need to do this with a for-loop?

Comment: Why would you expect calls `set(..., 1)` to ever set a value other than `1`? If you expect some cell to have value `2`, don't you think you need some other call with value 2 somewhere? --- And what does any of this have to do with *"How to print ..." in the title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a if condition inside the for loop to have a different value for the particular cell.

```
import Jama.Matrix;

public class Matrixnonsym {
public static void main(String args[]){
     Matrix Mytest=new Matrix(5,5);
     for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
         if(i == 0){
               Mytest.set(i,i,2);
         }
         Mytest.set(i,i,1);
         Mytest.set(i+1,i,1);
      }
    Mytest.print(9,6);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never used Jama before, but from the Javadoc I think you could just do:

```
import Jama.Matrix;

public class Matrixnonsym {
public static void main(String args[]){
    Matrix Mytest=new Matrix(5,5);
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        Mytest.set(i,i,1);
        Mytest.set(i+1,i,1);
    }
    Mytest.set(0, 0, 2.0) 
    Mytest.print(9,6);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import Jama.Matrix;

public class Matrixnonsym {
    public static void main(String args[]){
    Matrix Mytest=new Matrix(5,5);
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
            if (i==0) {
                Mytest.set(i,i,2);
            } else {
                Mytest.set(i,i,1);
            }
            Mytest.set(i+1,i,1);
        }
        Mytest.print(9,6);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import Jama.Matrix;

public class Matrixnonsym {
  public static void main(String args[]){
     Matrix Mytest=new Matrix(5,5);

     // first column
     Mytest.set(0,0,2);
     Mytest.set(1,0,1);

     // others columns
     for(int i=1; i<4; i++){
         Mytest.set(i,i,1);
         Mytest.set(i+1,i,1);
     }

     Mytest.print(9,6);
  }
}
```

Or

```
import Jama.Matrix;

public class Matrixnonsym {
  public static void main(String args[]){
     Matrix Mytest=new Matrix(5,5);

     for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
         Mytest.set(i, i, i == 0 ? 2 : 1);
         Mytest.set(i+1, i, 1);
     }

     Mytest.print(9,6);
  }
}
```